# SPA - Can I build an application without entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breeze, single-page-application, durandal

I need to develop an application using SPA, but I dont want to use Entity Framework. my database is Oracle and there already existing stored procs. I need to reuse them.

Is it possible to develop SPA application without EF?

Can anyone help me by providing some links/examples for this.

Comment: Are you using a specific SPA template?

Comment: no. I am not. I am planning to use Durandal and breeze for communication.

Answer (score 1):

Durandal is a client side framework and Entity Framework is a Server side framework.

Neither has a dependency on the other.

Breeze is also a client side framework and works much like Entity framework but does not have any dependencies on it.

You will not have any problems using Durandal Any data provider of your choosing.

Breeze on the other hand.. is designed to work well w/ Entity Framework.  But they claim on the site that its server technology agnostic.

Comment: Thanks. but how to do it with breeze. Whichever examples I have seen, its using EF with breeze.  do you have an example?

Comment: BreezeJs doesn't dictate the server technology.  http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/hosting-aspnet

Comment: Also the NoDB and Edmunds sample projects on Breezejs.com show off how to use Breeze without EF  http://www.breezejs.com/samples